# printing a (singly) linked list in c++

Tags: c++

OK, first I have my node structure

```
struct node {   
    string s;   
    node * next; 
};
```

And It's located within a class

```
    class strSet{
private:

    node * first;
```

And I can construct the list, and i've made checks to see it's being constructed (it is), but when i try and print it.. "Empty Set" is printed

This is my code to "print" it: (I've tried many variations of declaring a temp pointer, and still nothing)

```
node *temp = new node;
    temp = first;
    if (temp == NULL) cout << "Empty set" << endl;
    else {
    //  node * temp = new node;

        while (temp != NULL){
            cout << temp->s << endl;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks

EDIT: I have a function that makes a singleton list (this is for an assignment), the code is:

```
node *first = new node;
first->s = s;
cout << first->s << endl;
first->next = NULL;
```

The third line prints out the element when I add it

And yes i know there is a memory leak

Comment: How do you know that you have anything in it?

Comment: Show us the code to insert a node.

Comment: where is your last segment of code run? Inside a class member of strSet? If you do not initialize first with anything, i would expect the outcome that you are receiving...

Comment: It may help to post the complete code...

Comment: Why don't you use good old std::deque and make your life much simpler.

Comment: You have a memory leak here. I believe you should write `node *temp = first;`.

Comment: Check the edit, and yes, within a class member

Comment: @sad_man for an assignment, i have no choice

Comment: @codaddict, i have 5 files of code for this complete program. the code i posted is all i'm using for this certain problem i'm having, so i think the rest is unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

```
node *temp = new node;
temp = first;
```

can be condensed to -

```
node *temp = first ; // An unnecessary memory leak in earlier case.
```

Other than that print logic seems to fine. You didn't show the important part of how the linked list is formed.

---

```
node *first = new node;
first->s = s;
cout << first->s << endl;
first->next = NULL;
```

This is not a linked list at all. You are just creating an instance of type `node*` and just copying the `s` to it.

Comment: that was one of the things i tried, i posted my latest version of the code, but i'll go back to that, thanks

Comment: I wanted to write my output function for testing purposes before other functions that would create an n sized linked list.  Shouldn't it still print the value? the function there is supposed to create a "linked list" with one element

Comment: @ABlok - Even for printing the linked list elements, you should not create a new node in the print function. print function should get a reference to the first element of the node. i.e., `void print( node* firstNode );`. In the function, you need to loop over until the `next` points to **NULL**

Comment: unfortunately this is for an assignment, i was given a header file to work with containing   void output() const;  to use as my output function, so i cant pass in a parameter

Comment: @ABlok - Linked lists are very easy, if understood properly. Draw the diagram of how a single linked list must look like and understand it. All the best for your assignment.

Answer (score 0):

```
node *temp = new node;
```

this line is unnecessary and leaks memory;
The rest of the printing routine is correct, and therefore if "Empty Set" is printer therefore the set IS empty

Comment: hmm.. can you take a look at my function that adds a note (in the edit), maybe that's wrong?

Comment: @ABlok: The routine seems correct for setting the initial node. How do you add later nodes?

Comment: I haven't implemented that function yet.  I wanted to have my output function working for at least one node before I started on adding more.

Comment: @ABlok: If you provide a complete(but preferrably reasonably small) compilable example, I'll be able to help you

Comment: i couldn't get it compiled as one file.. too much seperate compilation going on, i have 2 headers and 3 cpp files, but thanks for the offer

Comment: @ABlok: ok, just provide all code you have. Edit your question and list all the files with their contents. Just try to get rid of irrelevant things first, if there are any(such as additional functions which aren't used etc.)

Comment: i think this will be easier, i included a makefile for you
http://www.mediafire.com/?1ip3lijk1uy2io0
my main program is setcalc.cpp, and you might notice i have a bunch of vector stuff.. ignore all of that, my previous assignment was to implement this with vectors, this assignment we change the vector to a linked list (in the strset files).. what im trying to do is declare a singleton, 's' command, and then output it, 'o' command.. i haven't implemented many functions using linked list, they're mostly for the vector

Comment: @Ablok: There is one OBVIOUS error that strikes me: you didn't mention that the creating routine you provided was a class member, and that class already has `first`. In your function, change `node *first = new node;` to `first = new node;`. Otherwise you ignore your class's first member and create an unrelates (but homonymous) variable that later gets discarded. Try and see if this helps

Comment: good catch, sorry i didn't mention that. it still prints "Empty Set" however

Answer (score 0):

From the small quantity of code you posted, it should work, so my guess would be that something is wrong with the construction of the list.

Now, there are some incoherences in your code - the useless "new node" for temp, as stated, but also having your (temp == NULL) ; this test could be directly operated with "first". Of course, make sure the strSet initializes first to null.

Then only you'd create temp before the while() and after the else. It's more logical (and a bit more optimal, though you're not winning much there - but you'll gain in readability).